Im in a Defi liquidity mining poods are locked in the mining pool so I need help to withdraw my locked funds please. I need help to withdraw my funds
I have joined a Defi liquidity mining pool four months ago for the first month I was getting income in my mining liquidity pool every day but one day I was transfering 6000usdt from my Trust wallet to my Gate.io account but instead 10,082.075 USDT withdrawn to a different address which Im not recogniseing but when I contacted the Defi liquidity mining pool assistance Rachel conlon representing herself as a Binance assistance she said that my assests have been transferred to the Defi liquidity mining pool and it will be pledged for 15 days because I have joined the VIP Pool and I will get double income for the next 15 days and after 15 days I will be able to withdraw my locked funds to my Trust wallet  but now it has been nearly three months my funds are still locked and Im not able to unlock my funds to transfer it to my Trust wallet. Im still getting double income every day and my assests has reached 1.7 million USDT in the so called Binance Defi mining pool but my Assests are locked so I need help to withdraw my locked funds please.thanks.
